# Why does this sed command to match number not work?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

My command is like this:

```
echo "12 cats" | sed 's/[0-9]+/Number/g'
```

(I'm using the `sed` in vanilla Mac)

I expect the result to be:

```
Number cats
```

However, the real result is:

```
12 cats
```

Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks!

Comment: For linux, you can use the `-r` option to sed, for Mac, you can use `-E`… which also works on some variations of Linux as a compatibility shim

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Expanding the `+` modifier works for me:

```
echo "12 cats" | sed 's/[0-9][0-9]*/Number/g'
```

Also, the `-E` switch would make the `+` modifier work, see choroba’s answer.

Answer (score 24):

`+` must be backslashed to get its special meaning.

```
echo "12 cats" | sed 's/[0-9]\+/Number/g'
```

Comment: Aha, thanks! (The Mac sed is too conservative to recognize the `+` modifier. The `-E` switch turns on extended regular expressions where `+` works unescaped.)

Answer (score 3):

Use perl, this will work on unix or linux.

```
echo "12 cats" | perl -pe 's/\d+/Number/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

In a very mystic way that is not explained (at least in resources I have so far..),
You should check up the next terms:

globbing (in the context of bash),
regex,
extended regex

For your question it seems that the expr' you gave to sed is a regex or extended regex....so by a tutorial I read you should insert also the -r before your actual command in sed...

echo "12 cats" | sed -r 's/[0-9]+/Number/g'

Works for me in an Ubuntu 16.04 , bash.

Comment: I didn't see it is 4 years ago....probably my answ is not crucial any more haha.....nevertheless it emphasizes my first line in the answer.

Comment: Expanding the + operator is the right way to go because it's more portable.